# Android AccountManager permission for a single custom account type

Tags: android, permissions, accountmanager

I'm writing an app for Android and I'm now trying to login/signup with the server I wrote.
I thought it'd be nice to use the AccountManager to do that so I read a tutorial about it.
In the tutorial it was told that I need the following permissions:

```
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS
```

When installing the app, Android says that the app has permission to
"Your accounts
Act as account authenticator, manage the account list, use account authentication credentials."
That seems a little scary to me and I think that many potential users won't install my app because of that.
I only need to access **my custom** account type. Not the user's Facebook or Google accounts.
In the [tutorial](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/), there is an [image](http://udinic.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/access_request.png?w=230&h=384) that shows Android saying the app has "Full access to an Udinic account".
I've been looking for how to do that for a few hours now but couldn't find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: "If you try to get an auth-token from an authenticator that was created by a different app, which was signed using a different signing key, the user will have to explicitly approve this action" -- please post your code where you are doing that, as this is the code that should trigger the image you are seeking.

Comment: I only need to get an auth-token from my authenticator. Is there no way I can do that without some of the permissions?

Comment: That I cannot say. I have avoided this area of Android for much the same reasons as you are expressing: the permissions are just plain scary. Eventually, I will bite the bullet and try to work out solutions that may involve fewer permissions, but that won't be until next year at my current pace.